# Mongoose insertMany with a possible lookup on a populate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I have a MEAN application and I am allowing users to upload a CSV containing multiple Event rows. After praising the CSV I have a list of Event objects and I can insert the records using mongoose insertMany. I have an Event and Attendee schema like this (simplified for this question).

```
var EventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    date: Date,
    location: String,
    speaker: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Attendee' },
});

var AttendeeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstname: String,
    email: {type: String, unique : true},
    speaker: Boolean,
});
```

My issue is when users are uploading the CSV they will only know the email address of the speaker but not the ObjectId. This email will always be unique. While performing an Event.insertMany() is there a way to do a Attendee.findOne on the email and populate the speaker field with an ObjectId ref to an Attendee on each Event as they are inserted.

Comment: Hello. Why do you don't want do it sequentially, first prepare Attendee object and then do Event.insertMany()?

Comment: I am not an expert of mongoose(mongo) and this is not direct answer, but you can achieve by doing at first query against AttendeeSchema to get speaker and then use that in insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must do it sequentially:

```
let email; //you know this email
let events;// prepared events data but without speaker id

Attendee.findOne({email: email}).then(result=>{
    events.forEach(event=>event.speaker = result._id);
    return events:
})
.then(events=>{
    return Event.insertMany(events);
})
.then(results=>{
    /*something results handle*/
})
.catch(err=>{
    throw err;
})
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid doing it sequentially but this definitely works. I ended up using Attendee.find({speaker : true}) to return a list of all speakers and then created a map with the email as the key and the id as the value. I then prepared my list of Events and used the Event.insertMany(events);